# I don't see monsters because of my spells

Tags: path-of-exile

This league I am trying a new build: [Spellsigner + Volatile Dead](https://www.poebuilds.net/slinger-vd2) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc6VVH1WgPI)). So far I like build potential (damage and defense) and I'd like to continue playing it.

But I have a big problem with it because attacking will trigger so many effects, what it's very hard to see something else around me: monsters in the distance and  in  melee range, objects to click nearby, passages, etc.

[Here is screenshot in steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2137783210) to have an idea and it's maybe 1/3 of what happens if I start spamming attack and orbs (up to 60 orbs!) are auto-moving for mobs, everything is flashing, moving in various direction, covering, popping.. I can barely see anything other than orbs.

What can I do? Is there some way to reduce effect of this spells (or in general - all spells effects)? Make something less visible? Making other object more visible? Anything?

Comment: Tags should describe the problem, not the answers. As nothing in the question seems exclusive to any console, console tags shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is just a partial answer - but it's too long for a comment]

Almost every spell can be affected by a cosmetic effect to change it appearance on the screen. But I don't know them well enough to say which ones could help you.

Those effects are purely cosmetic. Most of them can only be bought for real money (1). Therefore, they are likely designed to be more impressive than the default effects. While you are looking for less impressive effects. So there might be none that fit your requirements.

If anyone has actual suggestions, feel free to create a new answer so I can upvote you.

---

(1) Path of Exile is free-to-play. Selling cosmetic effects is a major source of income to pay for continued development.

Comment: The shop effect change it to black: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov7na2zBtno , it's way more appealing.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm glad my answer set you on a path to a solution you like. Enjoy the game!

Answer (score 3):

**There is not.**

You can both:

- Adapt your eyes to the flashy-confusing-exploding-MichaelBayApproved-gameplay your build create.
- Change your build to something you can handle.

PoE offers a lot of different ways to build your characters, a lot of mechanics you can sum togheter to obtain unique effects. A lot of build are based on obtaining an enormous number of cast per seconds, wich result in a very messy screen. If it's too much for you, try something that is easier on the eye. I played a similar build and others wich where even worse in terms of "things on the screen" and sometimes I found that it was too much for me and I switched in something else less shiny.

Comment: In another guide (using same skills, but with different skills/gear) the guy mentioned it as one of the *contrā*. I don't want to accept your answer straight away, but it could be what you are right and the only thing I can do is not to use builds like this one. I was hoping to get answer with some kind of tweaks, mods (legal modifications of course), maybe even existing settings to reduce character skills intensity..